# Is it possible to run command after run an app on the same terminal?

Tags: shell

I need to run command after running an app, but I'm not sure that it is possible because if my app is running the terminal run app. ( I need it for my Jenkins pipeline )

Do you know if it possible please ?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean, and what the difference is between a program and an "app". Is your app running in the foreground of the terminal, and you want to suspend it and run some other command?  What do you mean by "after"?  If the app has finished running, you should be able to do whatever you want with the terminal.

Comment: I try to be ore clear. My app is running and I've got message that the app is accessible on ipaddress in terminal. Now i want to curl some page of it app but if my app is running it's impossible. I found a buffer solution using operator '&' after start my app : yarn start & , then my shell script can be execute but i've got a failure in my  Jenkins job

Answer (score 0):

That kind of question is common when we have an application that is supposed to run as a service. There are a couple of problems with that approach, though. The first one is, well, your application wasn't quite prepared to run as a service or as a daemon. That's why most people nowadays package their applications as Docker images and deploy them as such.

Jenkins by design kills all processes started in each step after its end. If you don't want that behavior, try setting the `JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE` variable and setting it to "dontKillMe". Something like this:

```
sh "export JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe"
sh "myApp &"
```

Depending of your Jenkins version, it might be needed to also set the `BUILD_ID` variable to "donKillMe".

Best regards.